# How to use init-method with autowired dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

If there is a bean with init method:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.MyBean" scope="prototype" init-method="init">
```

The init-method:

```
public void init(MyBeanHolder holder) {
    this.myBean = holder.getMyBean();
}
```

The problem is the `init` method does not autowire bean. So the question is how can I use `init` with injected dependencies?

Comment: Why don't you autowire `myBean` directly? Would be easier to unit-test, read, maintain etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `init-method` (or `@PostConstruct`) is invoked after all Properties are injected. - So just inject your `MyBeanHolder holder` like every other dependency, and then use them in your `init` method via `this.holder`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Autowired
private MyBeanHolder holder;

public void init() {
    this.myBean = holder.getMyBean();
}
```

The `init` method will be called after the `MyBeanHolder` is injected.